# How do I write Meteor packages in Coffeescript?

Tags: meteor

I use CoffeeScript [CS] /heavily/ in my meteor sources. In fact, everything in my project is written using CS. I want to write packages by the same token. How should they be organized, declared, and written so they leverage the power of the CS dialect while maximizing testability and portability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you need only `api.use('coffeescript');` in your `Package.onUse` and `Package.onTest` in order to write your packages in CoffeeScript. See [the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/coffeescript) for an outline of the namespacing quirks.

Here's a simple example of a package called `safe` which contains the following four files:

**package.js**

```js
Package.describe({
  name: 'safe',
  summary: 'Encrypt strings to keep them safe (or not)'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.3');
  api.export('Safe');
  api.use('coffeescript');
  api.addFiles('encrypt.coffee');
  api.addFiles('safe.coffee');
});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.use('safe');
  api.use('coffeescript');
  api.addFiles('tests.coffee');
});
```

**encrypt.coffee**

```coffee
# use the share object to export code to other files in the package
share.encrypt = (string) ->
  # a super strong encryption :)
  string.replace /[a-zA-Z]/g, (c) ->
    String.fromCharCode (if ((if c <= "Z" then 90 else 122)) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) then c else c - 26)
```

**safe.coffee**

```coffee
{encrypt} = share

class Safe
  constructor: (@string) ->

  encrypt: ->
    encrypt @string
```

**tests.coffee**

```coffee
Tinytest.add 'safe encryption', (test) ->
  safe = new Safe 'pandapants'
  test.equal safe.encrypt(), 'cnaqncnagf'
```

This should give you a template to start from. If you need additional clarification, just ask in the comments and I'll update the answer as needed.

Comment: 2.5 more questions @david-weldon: 1) _What is_ and _Where can I learn more about_ the `{brackets}` syntax (not a JSON object)? 2) Does it make sense to design a package around a `Mongo.Collection` instance? If so, does it make sense to define the constructor with a reference to the Mongo Collection instance or extend the instance directly?

Comment: 1. It's an example of [destructuring assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) - it's one of those CS tricks that most people didn't read in the docs but is hugely helpful. 2. Yes, we do a lot of this - one package per collection. See my post on [models](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/models) for a complete example of how to add a transform and other helper functions.